# How set option value selected for select tag with existing values

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

The `$output` array return option vlaues for the select tag that I print as `<?php print_r($store);?>` and When I tried to update this form I need to show the `store` as selected value and also select list must have the other existing values as same as before which come from `$output`.

Model:

```
public function getStore() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $store = $this->db->get('tbl_store_info');
        $data = $store->result();

        $output = array();
        $output[]='<option value="" disabled selected>Select Store</option>';
        foreach ($data as $row) {
            $output[]= '<option value="' . $row->store_id . '">' . $row->store . '</option>';
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function editEmployee($id='') {
        $empData=  $this->CommonModel->getEmployee_by_ID($id);
        $data['emp_list'] = $empData[0];

        $data['store']=  $this->CommonModel->getStore();
        $data['user_role']=  $this->CommonModel->getUserRole();
        $data['msg']=  $this->session->flashdata('usermsg');

        $this->load->view('common/topnav');
        $this->load->view('common/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('common/header');
        $this->load->view('common/title-header');
        $this->load->view('employee/editEmployee',$data);
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
 <label for="store">Store:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="store" name="store" required>
    <option value="<?php echo $emp_list->store_id; ?>" selected><?php echo $emp_list->store; ?></option>
    <?php print_r($store);?>
  </select>
</div>
```

I just want this `<option value="<?php echo $emp_list->store_id; ?>" selected><?php echo $emp_list->store; ?></option>` as selected value.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve and how you've tried it. Could you re-ask your question in other/clearer words? And paste more relevant code?

Comment: I edited the question with clearer words, please take look @Jeff

Comment: still not enough code to find out what you're doing here. One thing I can already say is, that `print_r($store)` is not the right choice. Make a `foreach($store as $html)` and echo `$html`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building the HTML inside your Model (which is usually a bad practice) one you get to the View you have no way of selecting based on the id.

I would just rewrite the whole thing to output the HTML in the View not the Model.

But if you are looking for a quick fix just send the $id from the Controller into the model and have inside the foreach something like this:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $option_selected = '';
  if ($row->store_id == $id) {
    $option_selected = 'selected';
  }
  $option_str = "<option value='$row->store_id' $option_selected>$row->store</option>";
}
```

Comment: Do you have more information than "not working"? Without it there's not much I can do for you. Some specific error message? Logs?